# displaying distinct column value with corresponding column random 3 values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table employee with columns (state_cd,emp_id,emp_name,ai_cd) how can i display disticnt state_cd with 3 different values from ai_cd

the answer should be

```
state_cd  ai_cd
-------  --------
TX          1
            2
            5
CA          9
            10
            11
```

Answer (score 2):

This type of operation is normally better done in the application.  But, you can do it in the query, if you really want to:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by state_cd order by ai_cd) = 1
             then state_cd
        end) as state_cd,
       ai_cd
from employee e
order by e.state_cd, e.ai_cd;
```

The `order by` is very important, because SQL result sets are unordered.  Your result requires ordering in order to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just group by state_id and then count using count(Distinct column_name_)

```
select state_id from (select state_id,COUNT(DISTINCT ai_cd) as cnt  from employee  group by state_id) where cnt==3
```